# I can't display my single product from firebase with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

So im trying to show my product in product details page but I get nothing displayed.
I don't know where the problem is.. I would really need some help because i can't go further if this problem is not fixed. Thank you all.

```
product.service.ts
____________________

// Declarations
  bayonete: Observable<CutiteInterface[]>;
  loadBayonete: AngularFirestoreCollection<CutiteInterface>;
  bayonetProd;

// get all products
 GetBayonete() {
    this.loadBayonete = this.afStore.collection("bayonete");
    this.bayonetProd = this.loadBayonete.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((action) => {
        return action.map((a) => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as CutiteInterface;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;        
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
    return this.bayonetProd;
  }


// get single product
  getProductDetails(id) {
    return this.afStore.doc<CutiteInterface>("bayonete/" + id);
  }
```

Now in my details page I called my product and I can see in console the array , but i cant display it

```
detail-product.page.ts
_____________________

// Declarations
  product?: CutiteInterface;
  bayonetSingle: Observable<CutiteInterface[]>;
  bayonetID: string;

 constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private ProduseService: ProduseService,
    private afStore: AngularFirestore
  ) {

    this.bayonetID = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.ProduseService.GetBayonete().subscribe((products) => {
      this.product = products.find((a) => a.id === this.bayonetID);
      console.log(this.product);
    });
   
    this.bayonetSingle = this.ProduseService.getProductDetails(
      this.bayonetID
    ).valueChanges();
    console.log(this.bayonetSingle);
  }
```

And here i need to display it:

```
product-detail.html

 <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="12">
          <ion-list>
            <div class="product_descriere">
              {{ (bayonetSingle | async)?.description }}
            </div>
            <div class="product_reducere">
              {{ (bayonetSingle | async)?.reducere }} Lei ( {{ (bayonetSingle | async)?.tag }} )
            </div>
            <div class="product_pret">
              {{ (bayonetSingle | async)?.price }} Lei
            </div>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Comment: This doesn’t look like an issue with Firebase. First of all please don’t tell us what is not happening, tell us what are you expecting to see and what is the actual output that you are getting. For example, what are those console.log lines printing out? Second, I can see that you are retrieving the information into “product” but you are not using it to print the information, could you please explain how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try change method for single product like this:

```
getProductDetails(id) {
    return this.afStore.doc<CutiteInterface>("bayonete/" + id).get();
  }
```

and in You detal page change for this

```
this.bayonetSingle = this.ProduseService.getProductDetails(this.bayonetID)
.subscribe(proddet => {
    this.bayonetSingle = proddet.data();
    console.log(this.bayonetSingle);
    });
```

If this is not working try in You detal page creat all method, for example.

```
const dbRef = this.afStore.doc<CutiteInterface>("bayonete/" + id);
dbRef.get().subscribe(prdet => {
const data = prdet.data();
console.log(data);
});
```

Ok new version we make try rewrite some methods

```
// get all products
 GetBayonete() {
    this.loadBayonete = this.afStore.collection("bayonete");
   return this.loadBayonete.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(action => action.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as CutiteInterface;
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;        
      return { id, ...data };
    }))
    );
   }
  }
```

and for single product

```
// get single product
  getProductDetails(id) {
    return this.afStore.collection("bayonete").doc(id).snapshotChanges();
  }
```

and in You component page something like this.

```
ngOnInit():void {
this.ProduseService.getProductDetails(this.bayonetID).subscribe(px => {
const data = px.payload.data() as CutiteInterface;;
this.beyondSingle = data;
// for test purpose
console.log(bayonetSingle.description);
}
```

And in you html page change this

```
<div class="product_descriere">
          {{ (bayonetSingle | async)?.description }}
        </div>
```

for this

```
<div class="product_descriere">
              {{ bayonetSingle.description }}
            </div>
```

and You make try this

```
<div class="product_descriere">
              {{ bayonetSingle.description | async }}
            </div>
```

If You have any question don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Hello thanks for helping !! I've tried your methods , but i get erros with: "ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'" and console.log gets me 'undefined'.  The problem is on the html page , i guess async pipe isnt working. But the function    this.bayonetSingle = this.ProduseService.GetBayonete().subscribe(
      (products) => {
        this.product_single = products.find((a) => a.id === this.bayonetID);
        return console.log(this.product);
      }
    ); gets me the entire document so i just have to display it .. idk how

Comment: This is very strange, because today, while working on my project, at some point the download of data by the sevice,  stopped working, and putting the method directly into the component works fine. It is very mystical :)

Comment: Can you please sir help me with this ? I mean if you have any solution.. It will be perfect

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/qkH3wNj) - This is a screenshot of consoling the method , but i can't get a solution to show it xd omg it drives me crazy

Comment: I changed all my code to this new methods , but here on the test   console.log(bayonetSingle.description); it cannot find this variable i tried with this , but then says "description doesnt exist on type Observable<CutiteInterface> ... I tried to console log the data , but i get undefined. ??

Comment: So at this point I don't know what else to do, I can check class if the variables are correct and if they are data in this field